# fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: encryption, c, openssl

I run:

```
gcc bruteforce.c -o bruteforce -lcrypto
```

There is a header file `#include <openssl/evp.h>`
The code perfectly works in another machine But it has the following error in my current PC.

```
bruteforce.c:1:25: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this? is either the `libssl-dev` or `libssl1.0-dev` package installed?

Comment: @steeldriver you may want to make that into an answer, ie explain that you need the dev libs for openssl installed - I was going to make that into an answer but didn't want to be basically repeating your comment

Comment: my Ubuntu version is `ubuntu 16.04 LTS` and i tried to install both `libssl-dev` and `libssl1.0-dev` but when i install `libssl-dev` i get the output                                                    `libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14).`
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.` and when i try to install `libssl1.0-dev` i get error                                                        `E: Unable to locate package libssl1.0-dev`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libssl1.0-dev'`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libssl1.0-dev'`

Comment: Perhaps the file got moved or deleted? the first thing I would try is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libssl-dev`

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is almost correct but only works if you have already solved the problem. It led me to this solution:

```
sudo apt install -y libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask the packaging system:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ dpkg -S /usr/include/openssl/evp.h
libssl-dev:amd64: /usr/include/openssl/evp.h
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but `dpkg -S` works for installed packages! So it will not work on OP system. [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1121012/edit) your answer with link to [https://packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=openssl%2Fevp.h).